# AWS ApiGatewayV2 HTTP API with custom authorization lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, authorization, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to use a custom authorization lambda with ApiGateway**V2** for a HTTP API?
I know it's supported for a WebSocket API but there seems to only be support for AWS' own JWT authorizer for HTTP APIs. Does anyone know of a smart way to solve this?
The reason I'm asking is I need to validate third party tokens that do not fully follow OAuth2 standards (and therefore cannot use the out of the box JWT authorizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

This is now a feature added to HTTP API Gateways, more can be found in the [Introducing IAM and Lambda authorizers for Amazon API Gateway HTTP APIs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-iam-and-lambda-authorizers-for-amazon-api-gateway-http-apis/) announcement.

**Original**

Unfortunately Lambda custom authorizers have not been migrated to be supported by HTTP API Gateways yet.

> To build RESTful APIs, you can use either HTTP APIs or REST APIs from API Gateway. REST APIs offer a wide variety of features for building and managing RESTful APIs. HTTP APIs are up to 71% cheaper compared to REST APIs, but offer only API proxy functionality. HTTP APIs are optimized for performance—they offer the core functionality of API Gateway at a lower price.

The above quote from the [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/amazon-api-gateway-offers-faster-cheaper-simpler-apis-using-http-apis-preview/#:%7E:text=REST%20APIs%20offer%20a%20wide,Gateway%20at%20a%20lower%20price.) indicates that this is a light weight version of API Gateway at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll have to RestApi then.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I've managed to deploy a working HTTP API with custom lambda authorizer after many many fails... I've given up with OpenAPI body description within my template and I fully use now, core objects like AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Authorizer, AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration & AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route.. not as clean a openapi snippet but a working template :-)

Comment: that's not true anymore as custom lambda authorizers are supported by api gw v2-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer. How funny a few months of announcements can impact your answers :D

Answer (score 1):

It **is** possible to have a custom authorizer lambda with an AWS ApiGatewayV2 HTTP API.

For me at the moment (still early in my development) I actually have both a V2 WEBSOCKET **and** a V2 HTTP API using the same lambda for authentication, and both APIs using another lambda for the route handling -- yes, only 2 lambdas handling both APIs.

It is a bit of a mess because each API type has different event formats.

I created the WEBSOCKET API first and got the authorization lambda for it working first using OAUTH "client_credentials" and JWTs.

Then I added the HTTP API -- but it did require specifically declaring (I use terraform) the $default stage, a deployment, an integration, and a route with a $default route_key.  The route is where the "CUSTOM" authorizer gets tied in.  The point here is that using the so-called "quick create" V2 HTTP api does not appear to allow a custom authorizer.